# Prevent CKEditor filtering Radiant Tags (non-valid HTML tags)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, radiant

I'm using CKEditor with refinerycms (rails CMS) I've also added basic support for [radius tags](https://github.com/jlong/radius) (they are the tags used in Radiant, another rails CMS) so I'm able to list some elements from the model in the page just inserting a code.
The problem is that the radius tags mimic html:

```
<r:product_listing category="products" list_as="grid"/>
```

When using CKEditor to modify the page contents it thinks the radius tags are invalid HTML, which is correct and the expected behaviour, but I can't find the way to tell CKEditor to just ignore those tags.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Turned out that the tag was being filtered by the [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) method in rails being called by RefineryCMS.

Comment: Your link was also useful thanks, but @Reinmar response was really complete.

Comment: indeed, great solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of issues do you have with custom tags? And on which browsers?

I checked that CKEditor preserves this tag, but wraps entire content with it. To avoid that you have to edit [`CKEDITOR.dtd`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd), namely:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty[ 'r:product_listing' ] = 1;
```

But that still may not be enough. To have better support you'd need to make more changes in this object - especially important is to define what can be its parents and that it's an inline tag. For example:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.p[ 'r:product_listing' ] = 1; // it is allowed in <p> tag
CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline[ 'r:product_listing' ] = 1;
```

This still may not be enough - for example you'll most likely won't have copy&paste support.

So, if you need more reliable support I'd try a little bit different way. Using [CKEDITOR.dataProcessor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor) you can transform this tag into some normal one when data are loaded into editor and when data are retrieved transform it back to that tag.

Example solution:

```
// We still need this, because this tag has to be parsed correctly.
CKEDITOR.dtd.p[ 'r:product_listing' ] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline[ 'r:product_listing' ] = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$empty[ 'r:product_listing' ] = 1;

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function( evt ) {
            var editor = evt.editor;

            // Add filter for html->data transformation.
            editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    'r:product_listing': function( element ) {
                        // Span isn't self closing element - change that.
                        element.isEmpty = false;
                        // Save original element name in data-saved-name attribute.
                        element.attributes[ 'data-saved-name' ] = element.name;
                        // Change name to span.
                        element.name = 'span';
                        // Push zero width space, because empty span would be removed.
                        element.children.push( new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( '\u200b' ) );
                    }
                }
            } );

            // Add filter for data->html transformation.
            editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    span: function( element ) {
                        // Restore everything.
                        if ( element.attributes[ 'data-saved-name' ] ) {
                            element.isEmpty = true;
                            element.children = [];
                            element.name = element.attributes[ 'data-saved-name' ];
                            delete element.attributes[ 'data-saved-name' ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Now `r:product_listing` element will be transformed into span with zero-width space inside. Inside editor there will be a normal span, but in source mode and in data got by `editor#getData()` method you'll see original `r:product_listing` tag.

I think that this solution should be the safest one. E.g. copy and pasting works.

Comment: Wow, impressive response, thanks! I've used your code to create a custom plugin. I've added some more sugar, like making the element non-editable in the wysiwyg mode, and using the contents on the tag to create a message for the user (e.g. the text inside the span element is changed to "Listing products with type 'Services'")  I'm trying to give it an special style when showin up in the wysiwyg mode to also nail the presentation. Again, thanks!

Comment: Cool :) I forgot to mention about making it non-editable. And that we're currently working on widgets implementation (https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9764) - it's planned for 4.1 and it will make preserving custom code easier.

Answer (score 0):

u can also add  as protected source, so no filtering or parsing will be done.

```
config.protectedSource.push(/<r:product_listing[\s\S]*?\/>/g);
```

just add these line to your config.js ([\s\S]*? is for any random content)
check out http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource